# How to shows values that matched with multiples values using query in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

So apparently I try to list some IP from buyer side that matched with some parameters based by current table:

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JH3l.png)

I like to lists all of IP's that have been used together by seller and buyer similar like this

[Desirable Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fylp0.png)

Is there any query function in google sheets can solved this problem? since index match function only returns one IP value that matched first if there are 2 matched pairs. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get a data base as follows (in F2)

```
=sort(split(arrayformula({ A2:A7 &"|seller|" & B2:B7 ; C2:C7 &"|buyer|" & D2:D7}),"|"))
```

then get unique values in J2

```
=unique({A2:A7;C2:C7})
```

and finally search all datas corresponding to unique values

```
=iferror(join(char(10),,query({$F:$H},"select Col3 where Col2='"& K$1 &"' and Col1='"& $J2 &"' ")))
```

you have to duplicate that formula

[image]